# Mod-rewrite rules to manipulate query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

Okay. First, I know there are multiple answers to a question like this here at StackOverflow, but they only helped me part of the way.
Unfortunately a lot of the answers are very specific and only help on the case of the original asker.
So it would be nice if I could get an explanation that might also be extendable to other users' questions (and for myself if I need to use this in other pages). That said, my issue is the following:

I've been trying to use mod_rewrite to simplify my URLs to something easier for my users to type in the address bar.
So I've got to edit .htaccess to hide .php extensions externally and edited all the links on the code to follow.
The rewrite rules I have found to work are the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,L]

# Assume php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

These only deal with external redirection, but for me I don't really think internal redirection was needed, since I'm fine with just writing the short form of the URLs.
No reason hiding the extension if you just add them back in the html forms, right?

I draw users pages by receiving the username through the GET method.

```
www.webpage.com/userpage.php?view=username
```

What I want is the URL to become

```
www.webpage.com/user/username
```

When I finally got a rule that worked for this, the CSS file wasn't loading. Images could load or not depending on the rule I was using.
I scrapped the one I wrote because it was not only doing that but also were adding paths elsewhere.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]) userpage.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Basically this rule was applying '/userpage/' to all the links on the domain, regardless of what I typed in the address bar.
And when I typed the complete to it with the userpage.php it rewrote that to userpage/userpage/user.

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ userpage.php?view=$1
```

Was very similar, did the same results, but wasn't showing images either.
I know that the problem here is with relative paths, but just changing all the paths to absolute will remove all the portability from the code.

**I understand that what I really need here is to make it so ONLY pages with /user/ in the path to be rewritten.**

I not only would like to understand what kind of conditionals do I need to apply to the rule only change what I want, and not everything else, but I would really love if someone could tell-me if there is a way for the page to be inaccessible through the full path.

E.g. www.fullpath.com/user/username display the page, but www.fullpath.com/userpage?view=username be inaccessible.

Comment: The CSS/image issue was certainly covered in other answers (`<base href=>`). And rewriting `user/username` is one of the most common RewriteRules really. Neither involves working on THE_REQUEST or QUERY_STRING. Please elaborate what you tried exactly, and how something "broke".

Comment: I tried the '<base href=>' fix for the CSS/image issue, but that wasn't working. I tried also adding the full path on the rules and using the RewriteBase to fix it. That didn't work either. I don't really remember what was the precise code I used to get to that point though.

Comment: Nobody has any business using RewriteBase. Use absolute image/css URLs then if you couldn't make the simpler base href work. And again, for concrete advise on `user/\w+` rewrites, you need to make something up. Or your question will end up with copypasta as answer.

Comment: Basically the rule I HAD used was `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]) userpage.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]` but the workaround did not work on this. It still gives me a lot of trouble because it keeps adding "/userpage/" everywhere. It did not do what I wanted. It was too basic and not properly constrained. And yes, I really don't want a copy pasta answer.

Comment: It's exactly as it's on the question, in that same order (with just one of the 2 rules that break the code). I simplified the post a bit. There was a lot of irrelevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ userpage.php?view=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL

Comment: This just makes it forward internal links. External links don't work. So if you type "http://domain.com/page" it does not work because it doesn't know it is supposed to look for a ".php" file.

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `domain.com/page`? Does `page.php` exist? Does `domain.com/page.php` work?

Comment: Yes, yes and no. It's running on a local computer, not a dedicated server. If you just redirect internal pages it will just change the links I click to extensionless paths. But it doesn't read extensionless files as PHP if you don't use the code I already had on the .htaccess. Either way my main issue is not with normal pages. It's with the query on userpage.php.

Comment: Just wanting to leave this explicitly here: All the pages are on the root directory. There is no "/user/" directory, just the userpage.php file. I want to rename that as if there was an /user/ directory and then the username that is on the query string.

Comment: Well if `domain.com/page.php` gives 404 then `domain.com/page` will also give 404. Check updated code for `/user/...`

Comment: But `.../page.php` does not give an error. Sorry I wasn't clear. It was "yes, yes, no" to the questions in order. I really don't like using `<base>` tag because it can give headaches later, though with your code I found a workaround without using. I'm still using the .htaccess I had, but with your rules included in it. You mind if I edit the answer to accept it?

Comment: Or if you want me to edit just let me what you part you want to edit here?